# Windows 10 - Noise in the audio after installing Letasoft Sound Booster and using it for a while. How do I fix this now?

Tags: audio, noise

I have already uninstalled Letasoft Sound Booster, and I have reinstalled the drivers for Realtek Audio HD, and for the video card as well. But the noise remains. The problem arose after a while using Letasoft Sound Booster.

Comment: What kind of 'noise'? Is it volume-dependant? Buzzing in loud passages? Is this a laptop with small internal speakers? Many of those 'sound booster' apps will destroy small speakers in quite a short time.

Comment: It is an Itautec Note N8645 notebook, internal speakers yes. I believe they ruined the program. But it was my responsibility, I am not to blame others. I wanted the sound to be louder, and now the bass is hissing. The audio has passed 50, it is already possible to hear the bass with hissing.